# curl: RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding

Tags: c, ssl, curl, openssl, tls1.3

I am generating an X509 certificate through code (using OpenSSL APIs) for my server application. I have just added support for TLSv1.3 by adding TLSv1.3 ciphers in the supported list in my code.

There is no change in certificate generation and assigning RSA pub + private key to the certificate.

I have upgraded curl & OpenSSL libraries on client to enable TLSv1.3 connection. Upgraded Curl version: 7.63.0 & OpenSSL version: 1.1.1

I am seeing below error:

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <domain> (<ip-address>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: myCA.pem
  CApath: none
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [6 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [1781 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, decrypt error (563):
} [2 bytes data]
* error:0407008A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0407008A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding
```

Same error comes even with TLSv1.2 (using same upgraded client).

What am I missing here? Please help.

Comment: Most likely you did something wrong creating the cert(s). I take the filename `myCA.pem` to suggest you are using your own CA(s) and not self-signed. How many? Post an example (as a complete chain that should be verifiable, but not privatekeys unless they are expendable). Assuming you have them in convenient files, try commandline `openssl verify -CAfile root_and_any_imed.pem -purpose sslserver leaf_only.pem`

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old one, but I just had the same issue because I copied a PEM file from Windows with CRLF included instead of LF.

Use `cat -v cert.pem` to check for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was issuing a self-signed certificate by a self-created CA to use it for web development on localhost and was getting the same error. I tried to create a working SSL certificate multiple times, but always had this error `error:0407008A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding`, and I had multiple certificate authorities with the same CN registered in my operating system's trust source (/etc/ca-certificates/trust-source on manjaro).

How I solved the problem: I deleted all these "duplicates" and ran `update-ca-trust` to regenerate the list of CAs trusted by my system. Then imported my self-created CA once, generated an SSL certificate against it and used the crt and key in my web server - finally no `error:0407008A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding` when CURLing into it!

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread when searching this invalid padding error.  It seems as if there are multiple causes.  In my case, I was signing the leaf certificate with its own private key instead of the CA certificate's private key.

Answer (score 0):

‘ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR’ msg being displayed which I’ve seen in the past typically indicates an issue with the IIS binding and since this DNS is currently pointing directly to the web server, I’d suggest the following:

1. Switch the site back temporarily to the old certificate and retry simply loading page in a new private browser
2. If that works, next rebind the ‘new’ certificate to the IIS site and repeat another test (again inside a new private browser)

- you may need to remove any old certificates from HKLM store that match the same FQDN
- you may also need to possibly reboot the machine if something has gotten somehow corrupted within the IIS metabase

Answer (score -3):

curl: (35) error:0407008A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding

to avoid you can use the option -k

it works the same as we use postman and in the settings, turn off the SSL certificate verification option

Please find a sample curl and how to use -k option below

curl --location --request POST 'https://sample.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/v1/messages' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxx' --data-raw '{
"to": "91xxx",
"type": "image",
"recipient_type": "individual",
"image": {
"id": "56dxxxx",
"caption": "your-image-caption Saket jain how are you"
}
}' -k

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not a solution but instead a bad workaround. If you're going to ignore the certs anyways then why have them in the first place?